# Create a Script: Enumerate Access Control Lists

Tags: powershell, acl

I am "attempting" to create a script using a foreach loop in order to display the ACL's in that directory. Here are the instructions :

> Above the foreach condition, set a variable, $directory, to the contents of the current directory.
>
> Write a strong text command to enumerate the ACL of a file, using the $item variable in place of the file name.
>
> You'll need to use the following cmdlets:
>
> - `Get-ChildItem` (or any alias of `Get-ChildItem`, such as `ls` or `dir`)
> - `Get-Acl`

for my script I have,

```
foreach ($item in $directory) {
    
}
```

I am completely out of ideas on how to write the whole script.

Comment: Stop trying to write the whole script at once then - tackle one problem at a time: 1) figure out how to enumerate the contents of the current directory, 2) figure out how to store the results in `$directory`, and then 3) figure out how to use `Get-Acl` against a file.

Answer (score 0):

You have a pretty good start, it's actually quite simple. The first command below is storing the output of the command `Get-ChildItem "C:\"` in the `$directory` variable (C:\ can be any directory you'd like).

Once that's done, you just need to iterate through each file and run the `Get-Acl` command:

```bsh
$directory = $(Get-ChildItem 'C:\')  # Store cmd output

# Iterate through each file entry
foreach ($item in $directory) {
    Get-Acl $item  # Get the ACL
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even i am quite new to powershell, however, this is the code i wrote for a similar issue. Hope it helps:

```
  $BaseFolder = "<Path to Folder>"

#Since Get-Acl can only report on one file or directory at a time. 
$FolderPath = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $BaseFolder -Recurse -Force

$Output = @()


ForEach ($Folder in $FolderPath) {

  $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName

  ForEach ($Access in $Acl.Access) {

$Permissions = [ordered]@{'Name'=$Folder.FullName;'Users'=$Access.IdentityReference;'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights}

$Output += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties       

}

}


$Output | Export-Csv "<path>\$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss")).csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

## command dir lists the contents of directories in powershell

```
$directory = (dir) 

foreach ($item in $directory) {
     Get-Acl $item
}
```